# Add delay in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, delay

I have created a small function in jquery. I want it to load after some delay in time. But I am unable to execute this code with delay. Here is the Jquery code below.

```
$(function(){
        $('.fade').delay(5000).show();
        $('.sboxa').delay(5000).show()
    })
```

Here is the html code below:

```
<div class="fade"></div> <div class="sboxa"></div>
```

Please help in this functionality. Thanks

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: you want first show the .fade and after then you want to show .sboxa class ah?

Comment: can you post a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sequence animations you need to use callbacks in the `show()` method. Inside the callback you can use a `setTimeout()` to delay the showing of the next element.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.fade,.sboxa').hide();
  
    $('.fade').show(0, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.sboxa').show();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```css
.fade {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.sboxa {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fade">fade</div>
<div class="sboxa">sboxa</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Soviut is correct, but I think you should add a `slow` param to show or hide method like this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.fade,.sboxa').hide();
  
    $('.fade').show('slow', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.sboxa').show('slow');
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```css
.fade {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.sboxa {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fade">fade</div>
<div class="sboxa">sboxa</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery animation functions take an optional function argument that is executed after the animation is complete to allow for "chained" animations. No manual timers are needed.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.fade,.sboxa').hide();
  
    $('.fade').show(2000, function() {
            $('.sboxa').show("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.fade {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.sboxa {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fade">fade</div>
<div class="sboxa">sboxa</div>
```